# Flag message box overlapping in titlebar

Tags: discussion, bug, comment-flags

Recently I flagged some comments. I noticed when we flagged any comment one message box appeared: *Thanks for flagging!*

When the message box appears, and the same time we scroll the page, the message box is overlapping the title bar.

> Please check the below image for message box overlapping the title bar. The problem was observed in Mozilla Firefox 58.0.

[image]

> Please check the below image for a message box overlapping the title bar. The problem occurred in Google Chrome 64.0.3282.119.

[image]

And sometimes it appears on the left side of the title bar.

> Please check the below image for a message box appearing in the title bar.  The problem occurred in Mozilla Firefox 58.0.

[image]

> Please check the below image for the message box appearing in the title bar. The problem occurred in Google Chrome 64.0.3282.119.

[image]

**Is this a bug?**

Comment: MSE cross-site dupe: [“thanks for flagging” popup gets messed up when the comment is automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313453/289905)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comment flag notification on the top corner, why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372053/comment-flag-notification-on-the-top-corner-why)

Comment: @peterh check the timing of  question i asked question 3 days ago

Comment: @peterh none of the question are duplicate .. this one is reporting a bug and mine is asking about a specific behavior